# php cache mistake

Tags: php, caching, http-caching

I have single page in my control panel user which need secret code to
 access.

My sequence for doing this are :

1. go to "secret code request page" with a parameter which page i want to access.
2. check the secret code, if correct then fill the session variable with "hashed page name"
3. redirect to page i want to access.
4. this page check the "hashed session" whether match or not with this "page name"
5. if match, clear the session and show the entire page, if mismatch then redirect to initial page.

The problem is : at step 4, the page sometimes read the late session
update. sometimes it shows no value, but many times it shows the
correct value and if I refresh the page, the session still have
correct hashed data (at step 5, if match, i already clear the session
variable), howcome?

i try to change the session variable with data record with mysql, but
i got same result. the phpmyadmin shows the record already set, but
the page shows no data set. and otherwise, after record deleted, the
page still shows the previous record value.

is this means a problem with the cache? i also did the header no cache
such as :

```
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

but still same result i got. any suggestion guys?

updates : If i keep refreshing the page, after maybe 3 or 5 refreshed, it shows the correct value. how to make it realtime? so then if the session set, the page can directly check the value set, and if the session cleared, so the page will ask the secret code.?

Comment: even tried to look at debug console to see what and from where do you read , do you have proxy ?

Comment: whats the problem, why the page cannot show up the current value of session variable / mysql record value?

Answer (score 1):

dump out the session in step 4: print_r($_SESSION) to see if it's set or not. If not, you need to set it in Step 2 ***before*** you make the redirect.

Also don't forget to call session_start() on every file.

Comment: the sequence is correct and works in my localhost. but the result is not same when uploaded. try to print the session, it shows not the current value. and if i checked in mysql phpmyadmin, the data is correct but different from the page result.

Comment: Can you post the code? Try to check if the session exists: echo session_id(); - As you know sessions always correspond to a cookie, if for some reason the cookie doesn't get set initially, the session won't exist.

Comment: This might help too: if ($PHPSESSID) print "session exists";
else print "session does not exist";

Comment: the session is exist and have value, but the value appears on page is different with the current value. i found this problem when i try to use mysql as a session replace, the data appears is shows "a" when the phpmyadmin already shows the "b" (new value)